# Creating a new item in Grid ComboBox editor template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, mvc-editor-templates, kendo-combobox

I have setup a Kendo `Grid` with a column which contains a `ComboBox` editor template assigned. This works well and retrieves the items I am expecting:

```
columnSchema.push({ field: "Comment", title: 'Comment', editor: commentDropDownEditor, template: "#=Comment.Description#" });
```

Produces the following:

[image: Grid ComboBox column]

My issue is that I am now trying to extend the properties of the 'Comment' column so that users can enter new items i.e. comments that will, in turn, be saved to the database for reuse.

So far, I have done the following...

Setup the `commentDropDownEditor` function:

```
function commentDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoComboBox({
            suggest: true,
            change: onComboBoxChange,
            autoBind: false,
            optionLabel: "Select comment...",
            dataTextField: "Description",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                autoSync: true,
                transport: {
                    read: "CommentsAsync_Read",
                    create: {
                        url: "CommentsAsync_Create",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="' + options.field + '"></span>').appendTo(container);
}
```

Hooked up the `change` event to the following function:

```
function onComboBoxChange(e) {
    var combo = e.sender;
    // check if new value is a custom one
    if (!combo.dataItem()) {
        // select the newly created dataItem after the data service response is received
        combo.one("dataBound", function () {
            combo.text(combo.text());
        });

        // create a new dataItem. It will be submitted automatically to the remote service (autoSync is true)
        combo.dataSource.add({ Description: combo.text() });
    }
}
```

I can see the `onComboBoxChange` function being hit through the Console Window (including the line where the new item is being added to the combo box datasource) but the associated `Create` transport function is not being executed nor is the item being added to the `Combo Box`.

`Create` function in the `Controller` is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CommentsAsync_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Comment> comments)
{
    if (comments.Any())
    {
        //await _manager.CreateCommentAsync(comments);
    }
        return Json(comments.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Is there something I am missing/doing wrong here to get this to work?

Comment: Good work so far... So upvote for you..

Comment: Where are you sending this parameters with prefix 'models' `[Bind(Prefix = "models")]` to the Action `CommentsAsync_Create`